# Enumerate Elements in Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

So I am reading in my book, and some across this example:

Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$. We can enumerate its elements as:

$[\pm 1], [\pm 2], [\pm 4], [\pm 7]$

Can someone explain how the solution was found?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible modulo $n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Comment: Yeah but $2 mod 15 = 2$?

Comment: @pat what is $13 \pmod{15}$?

Comment: $[2] \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}^* \iff 2$ invertible mod $15 \iff \gcd(2,15) = 1$.

Comment: How does 2 mod 15 equal 1? Its 2..

Comment: Ohhhh, inverse mod. I understand now. Just realized I read it wrong.

Comment: $\gcd(2,15)$ is the *greatest common divisor* of $2$ and $15$. I didn't write $2\mod 15$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $[m]$ is invertible $\pmod n$ if and only if $m,n$ are relatively prime..

So to find all elements in $\mathbb Z_{15}^*$ you need to find all classes $[m]$ for which $gcd(m,n)=1$...